# Rails Conditional Auditing using Audited Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audit

I want to save audits only for special cases. Is there any way, I can do conditional Auditing?

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/237

Currently I enable/disable audit, whenever I want to use audit feature..

Comment: The answer to your question is shown in the link you posted! You have even commented on how to do it using a forked version! So not sure what you want?

Comment: Thank you Jamesc. I want to know if there is same kind of feature on audit/master branch too.The above link has merge conflicts.